# Changing the color of font depending on math expression within ng-style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

When I enter a number into the text box I want to color of the text of another text box below to turn red depending on the value entered but I'm not sure if I have my syntax for the ng-style correct with regards to the math expression. Thank you for helping!

```
     ng-model="approval.groupCreditLimit" ng-style="{'color':(approval.siteTotal + approval.siteCreditLimit) > approval.groupCreditLimit) ? 'red' : 'inherit'}"  class="form-control" name="groupCreditLimit" placeholder="Group Credit Limit" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this

```
ng-style="( (approval.siteTotal + approval.siteCreditLimit) > approval.groupCreditLimit) ? {'color': 'red'} : {'background-color': 'inherit'}"
```

[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/nzDWPriQpgrhCuYzpiDo?p=preview) is a working demo

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: no problem. if this answer is correct, don't forget to mark it as correct answer. cheers !!!!